# Having an unknown problem with Regex processing names

Tags: regex, regex-group

I'm parsing name strings that have strange compound formations.
The current formation that's giving me a problem is these names:

```
Edward St. Loe Livermore
Henry St. George Tucker III
Henry St. John
```

This pattern `(.*)(St\.\s\w+)\s(.*)` parses the first two names and completely ignores the third.

This pattern `(.*)(St\.\s\w+)|(St\.\s\w+\s(.*))$` returns the third name as well, but leaves off the surname of the first two.

I'm using this save [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/r/zGE7zf/1) to test the regex pattern

So far I can't figure out what pattern will return the surname in the match for all three names,
or if I need to do conditional statement in my code to parse the three element names separately, which seems inefficient.

TIA

Comment: You could try making the last group optional: `(.*)\s(St\.\s\w+)(?:\s(.*))?`: [https://regex101.com/r/Cgqiny/1](https://regex101.com/r/Cgqiny/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use this regex:

```
(.*)(St\.\s\w+)\s*.*
```

### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G8FATv/1)

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `(` | group and capture to \1: |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \1 |
| `(` | group and capture to \2: |
| `St` | 'St' |
| `\.` | . |
| `\s` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") |
| `\w+` | word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `)` | end of \2 |
| `\s*` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Comment: Wow. Thanks. That worked. What was missing in my logic? I don't understand why the extra asterisk made the difference.

Comment: Because it means 0 or more times, so optional

Comment: Oh. I see. Zero or more spaces, followed by zero or more other characters. I didn't recognize that space was the item screwing things up.

Comment: Oh crap. Your table breakdown explains it perfectly and I only skimmed it at first.